# Showing $\displaystyle{\frac{\psi(z)}{\Gamma(z)}=-e^{2\gamma z}\prod_{k=0}^{\infty}\left(1-\frac{z}{x_k}\right)e^{z/x_k}}$

Tags: special-functions, gamma-function, infinite-product, digamma-function

I want to show the following infinite product,
$$\frac{\psi(z)}{\Gamma(z)}=-e^{2\gamma z}\prod_{k=0}^{\infty}\left(1-\frac{z}{x_k}\right)e^{z/x_k}$$
where $x_k$ is the $k$th root of the digamma function.

This is what I've tried. As noted on the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function#Infinite_product_representation),
$$\frac{\psi(z)}{\Gamma(z)}=\frac{\Gamma'(z)}{\Gamma(z)^2}=-\frac{d}{dz}\frac{1}{\Gamma(z)}.$$
By Weierstrass's infinite product expansion of the reciprocal gamma,
$$\frac{1}{\Gamma(z)}=ze^{\gamma z}\prod_{n=1}^\infty\left(1+\frac{z}{n}\right)e^{-z/n}$$
taking the derivative,
$$\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{dz}\frac{1}{\Gamma(z)}&=\frac{d}{dz}\left[ze^{\gamma z}\prod_{k=1}^\infty\left(1+\frac{z}{k}\right)e^{-z/k}\right]\\&=(1+\gamma z)e^{\gamma z}\prod_{k=1}^\infty\left(1+\frac{z}{k}\right)e^{-z/k}-ze^{\gamma z}\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left(\frac{e^{-z/k}}{k^2}\prod_{n=1}^\infty \left(1+\frac{z}{n}\right)e^{-z/n}\right) \\
&=\frac{(1+\gamma z)}{z\Gamma(z)}-ze^{\gamma z}\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left(\frac{e^{-z/k}}{k^2}\frac{1}{ze^{\gamma z}\Gamma(z)}\right) \\
&=\frac{(1+\gamma z)}{z\Gamma(z)}-\frac{1}{\Gamma(z)}\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left(\frac{e^{-z/k}}{k^2}\right)
\end{align*}$$
and I am stuck. More precisely, I do not know how to make the connection to the roots of $\psi$.

Comment: Perhaps the Weierstrass factorization theorem helps?

Comment: For an entire function $f(z)$ with infinitely-many simple zeroes $x_{k}$, the Weierstrass factorization theorem states that $$f(z) =  f(0) e^{z f'(0)/f(0)} \prod_{k=1}^{\infty} \left(1-\frac{z}{x_{k}} \right)e^{z/x_{k}}.$$  Two conditions need to be satisfied, namely that $0 < |x_{1}| < |x_{2}| < \ldots$ , and that $\left| \frac{f'(z)}{f(z)} \right|$ is uniformly bounded on circles of radius $R_{n}$ that don't pass through the zeroes.  The expressions $f(0)$ and $f'(0)$ really mean $\lim_{z \to 0} f(z)$ and $\lim_{z \to 0}f'(z)$.

Comment: @RandomVariable. Is there a way to show it by taking the derivative of the reciprocal gamma?

Comment: @bob: of course no (how do you get a *product* as a result of taking a derivative?).